# Erro ao tentar criar tabela Excel com o ClosedXML

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, visual-studio-2015, office-open-xml

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação que gera uma planilha em Excel através do Visual Studio 2015 usando como referência o ClosedXML.
Conforme encontrei alguns exemplos na web, adicionei o mesmo ao código (using ClosedXML.Excel;), baixei a referência e a adicionei ao projeto e tentei criar uma planilha simples, como é mostrado como exemplo no próprio site do ClosedXml (https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

Adicionei o código abaixo, mas ao rodar o programa aparece o erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll Additional information: Não foi
>   possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
>   Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo
>   especificado.

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

É necessário configurar mais alguma coisa no Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando algumas dependências em seu projeto, 
instale a biblioteca via nuget com o seguinte comando:

```
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml
```

Comment: Olá, Carlos Eduardo! Realmente era isso! Instalei a biblioteca via nuget e funcionou. Muito obrigado! Abs!!!

Comment: Ótimo Leandro, se precisar estamos aí !